# Google Chart API over SSL

Tags: magento, ssl, charts, google-api, dashboard

Ok so since I applied an SSL Cert to our site the graphs in the dashboard have stopped working. i read this site

EDIT: forgot to add, im trying to get this working in the magento dashboard.

http://www.phpro.be/blog/detail/magento-dashboard-charts-not-working

which states to add "true" to the GetChartUrl() function within 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/graph.phtml

this works on a site not using SSL.

I then found this site

http://webguru.org/2009/11/09/php/how-to-use-google-charts-api-in-your-secure-https-webpage/comment-page-1/#comment-988

but this supposedly opens up opportunity for SQL injection and other malicious attacks.

next I found this site

http://store.ivvy.ru/blog/chartssl/

and followed the instructions but still the charts aren't working.

i tried changing

```
const API_URL='http://chart.apis.google.com/chart';
```

to both

```
const API_URL='//chart.apis.google.com/chart';
const API_URL='https://chart.apis.google.com/chart';
```

but neither worked.

Can anyone point me to any other examples / explanations, or explain how to get this working?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Firebug or another browser debug tool?  If so, what is the error on the Console tab when you load the page containing the charts.  I can tell you now, it's most likely due to trying to load a HTTP JS script over an HTTPS connection...which will fail.

Try using their latest API URL which supports HTTPS:
`https://chart.googleapis.com/chart`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, im not in work now until friday, but I will have a go friday morning and report back.

Comment: hmmmm, still no luck, iv even tried deleting all forms of cache (admin area, and manually via FTP) but no luck :/

Comment: the error in the console is this --> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)  then a massive url. if that helps.

Comment: or this

GET https://www.MYURL.co.uk/index.php/MYADMINAREA/dashboard/tunnel/key/128cf0074dea2163299dde8660f5330a/?ga=YTo5OntzOjM6ImNodCI7czoyOiJsYyI7czozOiJjaGYiO3M6Mzk6ImJnLHMsZjRmNGY0fGMsbGcsOTAsZmZmZmZmLDAuMSxlZGVkZWQsMCI7czozOiJjaG0iO3M6MTQ6IkIsZjRkNGIyLDAsMCwwIjtzOjQ6ImNoY28iO3M6NjoiZGI0ODE0IjtzOjM6ImNoZCI7czoyMDoiZTpBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFWWVNHOGEiO3M6NDoiY2h4dCI7czozOiJ4LHkiO3M6NDoiY2h4bCI7czo3MjoiMDp8fDAyLzIwMTJ8fDA1LzIwMTJ8fDA4LzIwMTJ8fDEwLzIwMTJ8fDE6fDB8MTAwfDIwMHwzMDB8NDAwfDUwMHw2MDB8NzAwIjtzOjM6ImNocyI7czo3OiI1ODd4MzAwIjt. . . 503 (Service Unavailable) 

prototype.js:2048

Comment: So the issue seems to be internal, since it's your own URL that is producing a 503 error.  If you have access to your server logs, I would comb through them and try and determine exactly what is causing a 503 error.

Comment: I dont have access to server logs :/ im on shared hosting, which has very minimal backend options compared to what iv seen before. Is there any other options? i sent the hosting company an message asking if they had a firewall set up and if it was blocking the url there reply was basically "its nothing to do with us" and then they tell me to go read the second link in my original post :/ quite unhelpful.

Comment: Well, from there you can only assume what the issue is, and try to pick things apart until you no longer receive the 503 error.

My assumption is that your URL Paramater value for `ga=` might be too long for the server.  The host may of set a byte restriction on it.  Since your parameter is about 415 characters long (or approximately 415 bytes), it might be a valid assumption.

Try the same url in your browser with `?ga=12345` and see if the page loads.  The charts obviously won't work, but the page shouldn't produce an error.

If you want to start a chat I could possibly help further.